# XML file containing multiple root elements

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I have a file which contains multiple sets of root elements. How can I extract the root element one by one?

This is my XML

```
<Person>
    <empid></empid>
    <name></name>
</Person>
<Person>
    <empid></empid>
    <name></name>
</Person>
<Person>
    <empid></empid>
    <name></name>
</Person>
```

How can I extract one set of `Person` at a time?

Comment: Your tag says "java", but it's not very obvious if you are looking for a library or a code solution. This question gets very broad...

Comment: This is not a valid XML document.

Comment: Valid xml file can't contain more than one root. But you have some options here: 1. Enclose your xml code into <Root> element and parse it via common java lib code (e.g. DocumentBuilder) 2. Read as text, enclose into <Root> tag and fallback to (1). 3. Parse it manually.

Comment: Laune and korifey, yes, but you mean [***well-formed***, not *valid*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085).

Comment: will you please help me in that how can I append a root element for this xml file via code.

Answer (score 10):

Use [`java.io.SequenceInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/SequenceInputStream.html) to trick xml parser:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.SequenceInputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class MultiRootXML{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        List<InputStream> streams = Arrays.asList(
                new ByteArrayInputStream("<root>".getBytes()),
                new FileInputStream("persons.xml"),
                new ByteArrayInputStream("</root>".getBytes())
        );
        InputStream is = new SequenceInputStream(Collections.enumeration(streams));
        Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(is);
        NodeList children = doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();
        for(int i=0; i<children.getLength(); i++){
            Node child = children.item(i);
            if(child.getNodeType()==Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                System.out.println("persion: "+child);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the correct answer based on the original question.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot parse your file using an XML parser because *your file is not XML*.  **XML cannot have more than one root element.**

You have to treat it as text, repair it to be [well-formed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085), and ***then*** you can parse it with an XML parser.

Answer (score -1):

If your XML is valid, using a SAX or DOM parser. Please consult the [XML Developer's Kit Programmer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28394/adx_j_parser.htm#ADXDK3000) for more details.