# Create single xml file from multiple xmls

Tags: java, xml, oracle, jaxb

My requirement is as follows:

1. I would like to use a JDBC to connect the Oracle which has xml as a table column and retrieve the records. I want all those retrieved xml records to be in one file.
2. I will parse those extracted  xmls using JAXB API and delete some of the tags for every xml i read . Then i would like to generate one single output file which consist of all the xmls that are edited

After retrieving the data from the table my output should look like this

#### Extracted_records.txt

```
<Record><tag1></tag1><tag2></tag2><tag3></tag3><Record>
<Record><tag1></tag1><tag2></tag2><tag3></tag3><Record>
<Record><tag1></tag1><tag2></tag2><tag3></tag3><Record>
<Record><tag1></tag1><tag2></tag2><tag3></tag3><Record>
```

After parsing and deleting the records my output file should look like this

#### Outputfile.txt

```
<Record><tag2></tag2><tag3></tag3><Record>
<Record><tag1></tag1><tag2></tag2><Record>
<Record><tag1></tag1><Record>
<Record><tag1></tag1><tag3></tag3><Record>
```

Comment: (1) Your XML files will have to have a single root element.  (2) What is your question?

Comment: BTW, `<Record>` element is never ended

Comment: You can read xml with multiple root elements. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30984236/xml-file-containing-multiple-root-elements/31274225#31274225