# Parsing single node xml file using Dom parser

Tags: java

Can we able to parse single node(having only one tag) xml file using Java

Example:

```
<Node
    e1 =" 1  "
    e2 = "asd " 
 /> 
<Node2
     e1= "2"
     e2 = " asdf"
 />
```

by using schema file or without using ?
I am able to parse if it contains root tag
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Yes, you can. [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/202153)

Comment: Sorry by mistakenly I have added wrong format of xml here is correct format please find below

Comment: I tried to fix the question format for you to display the XML correctly.  However, your XML does not seems to be even a valid one.  It is also confusing for what you meant by "single node".  Please fix your question to provide valid XML, and more explicit and clear question on the problem you are facing

Comment: and, I have changed your `\>` to `>`, not sure if it is what you intended to write, as `<.... \>` is not valid XML syntax

Comment: Hi by mistakenly I have added wrong xml format yesterday. Now I have edited with correctly one

Comment: I tried with DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

Comment: I am able to parse if it contains one root tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML file containing multiple root elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30984236/5221149)

Answer (score -1):

You need a class that can hold the object you are trying to parse (with the right annotations). It's really recommended generating it, because the annotations aren't always so intuitive to write.
Your Node element is your root element, you don't need any other wrapping element.
Try Googling for JaxB or other XML parsing libraries.

Comment: Question is asking *"using Dom parser"*, so saying that OP needs to use JAXB is not an answer.